# Getting work through a recruiter

Tags: recruitment, canada, terminology

I have been in contact with a number of people who's title is "recruiter". They all know of job prospects for multiple companies, so they don't seem to be attached to one company. I've heard getting work through a recruiter is generally a negative thing, as they take a portion of the pay as long as you continue to work for the employer they found for you. Is this true?

How exactly do recruiters work, do companies with an opening pay them to do this, and if the company is large enough have in house recruiters?

Comment: Don't overestimate them...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the recruiter said she has more contract jobs than full time ones. I don't understand what you mean by agency?

Answer (score 6):

It may vary in your country, but in my country and in my profession (software developer) the use of recruitment agents is the norm.  You don't pay a portion of your salary; the employer pays the recruiter a fee which is based on the salary offered.  This is usually a one-off lump-sum fee, not a continuous payment they get for as long as you work there.

It is the employer who is the recruiter's client, and the employer for whom they are performing a service.  Companies basically pay recruiters to filter out the weak applicants, which saves them time and money.

Comment: I know it's paranoid thinking, but could the employer decide to lower the salary in proportion to what they pay the recruiter, effectively transferring the cost to the employee? Or is this illegal?

Comment: All businesses weigh up their costs when making financial decisions, yes.

Comment: IT recruiters are a necessary evil, so long as you realize that they are evil, you can deal with them effectively.

Comment: @RichardU can you explain a little more? How are they evil and to whom?

Comment: @TickTack1 "Necesssary evil" is a common phrase. It doesn't always mean evil.